# Can't get my HTML form to NOT submit upon clicking Submit button

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form. I'm asked to write JS code to validate the data in the form and display results of the validation on the same page, without submitting the form. I'm told to have my JS function (which executes when Submit is clicked) return false so that the form is not submitted. I did that but still when I run my page, the results of form validation flash on the page for half a second and disappear as the form is submitted. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have in JS: (the first function adds an event listener to the submit button of my form)

```
function eventListener(){ 
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("sub");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate, false);
}

function validate(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById("book_3").value;
    if(input1=="" || input2=="" || input3=="")
        window.alert("Error: Please fill in all input fields");
    else if(isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2) || isNaN(input3))
        window.alert("Error: Please enter numbers in the input fields");
    else{
        var total1 = input1*19.99;
        var total2 = input2*86;
        var total3 = input3*55;
        var grandtotal = total1 + total2 + total3;
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var par = document.createElement("p");
        container.appendChild(par);
        par.innerHTML = "<h3>Basic XHTML (Quantity: " + input1 + "):</h3> $" + (total1)
                + "<br/> <h3>Intro to PHP (Quantity: " + input2 + "):</h3> $" + (total2)
                + "<br/> <h3>Advanced JQuery (Quantity: " + input3 + "):</h3> $" + (total3)
                + "<br/><br/> <h3>Final Total:</h3> $" + grandtotal;
    }
    return false;
}

window.onload = eventListener;
```

Comment: Put the submit listener on the form's submit handler, not the button. Forms can be submitted without clicking the button, and it's simpler to cancel the submit from the form's handler.

Answer (score 2):

pass the event to the validate function and set a preventDefault, like this:

```
function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code here
}
```

submit the form after validation with .submit() if needed;

Answer (score 0):

Just move the listener to the form:

```js
function stopSubmit(){
  return false;
}

window.onolad = function() {
  document.getElementById('f0').addEventListener('submit', stopSubmit, false);
}
```

```html
<form id="f0">
  <input value="foo" name="foo">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The listener should be on the form anyway since it can be submitted without clicking the button.

#### PS.

The form seems to submit anyway in stack snippets, but put it in a page and the code works.